# Being prompted to convert local account to a Microsoft account -- how to stop this?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I had to switch my Micrsoft account back to a local user account due to issues with offline file sharing.  When I had switched back to a local user account, every time I click on the start menu I get a prompt asking me to change the account back into a Microsoft account. This prompt is extremely annoying because I'll be typing in the search bar, say for File Explorer, and this window will pop up and take priority.

[image]

I can't seem to find any settings that would allow me to get rid of this stupid popup. I'd like to keep my account at a local account, which is where it's at right now, but the issue is that I am constantly badgered to make a Microsoft account.

Comment: A screenshot may be helpful to explain your problem.